weighted surface average vs volume average for some ocean data
I am plotting vertical profiles for some ocean data (360x, 270y, 50z) divided into regions. For each region I plot a profile of average data at each depth level and the volume average for that region. Here's my script to compute the volume (all depths) and surface (fixed depth) averages:
var='DFrE_TH';  %<--- choose a field to look at
field=AO.(var);  
regions={'NAt','NPa','ARC','EB','CB','shelf','slope'};

% Compute regional volume averages:
% get volume with grid cell (area * depth thichness)

z_thic_expanded = reshape(z_thic, 1, 1, []); % reshape to 1x1x50
vol=AO.area.*z_thic_expanded;

surface_averages=nan(length(regions),50);
volume_averages =nan(length(regions),1);

for r=1:length(regions)
    
    region_mask=AO.regions.(regions{r});
    region_mask(:,:,1)=0; %remove top layer since no data there
    
    tmp=field.data(region_mask==1);
    weight=vol(region_mask==1);
    
    volume_averages(r)=sum(tmp.*weight)/sum(weight);
    
    vol_sum=[];
    
    for d=2:50 
        
        region_mask2d=squeeze(region_mask(:,:,d));
        vol2d=vol(:,:,d);
        
        if any(region_mask2d(:)==1) % make sure there is some data at this depth for this region
            
            data2d=squeeze(field.data(:,:,d));
            
            tmp2d=data2d(region_mask2d==1);
            weight2d=vol2d(region_mask2d==1);
        
            surface_averages(r,d)=sum(tmp2d.*weight2d)/sum(weight2d);
            
            vol_sum=[vol_sum;sum(weight2d)];
        end
    end
    
    surf_avg=surface_averages(r,:);
    vol_avg=sum(surf_avg(~isnan(surf_avg)).*vol_sum')/sum(vol_sum);
    
    disp([num2str(volume_averages(r)) ' vs ' num2str(vol_avg)]);

end

To check if the the weighted mean of my surface averages (weighted by depth level thickness) is equal to the volume average for each region I displayed
nansum(surface_averages(r,:).*z_thic)/sum(z_thic(~isnan(surface_averages(r,:))))

but I didn't find the same result as volume_averages(r)
I don't undertsand why the weighted mean of the surface averages for a region is not equal to its volume average.
At the end of this code snippet, vol_avg ends up equal to volume_averages(r) but I would like weightedmean(surface_averages,z_thic) equal to volume_averages.
Let me know if you need more details or extra info.
